# Error retrieving Google Maps location from JSON

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I have an activity that shows a list of POI retrieved from a JSON document. When I tap a list element, it opens Google Maps app and shows the relative point on the map.

This works on the emulator, but not on physical devices because it looks for coordinates like xx,xxxxxxx instead of xx.xxxxxxx: that returns an "No results found" error.

Note that the device's UI language is italian.

This is a sample of the JSON:

```
[
        {
        "id": "1",
        "latitude": "48.8586006",
        "longitude": "2.2939799",
        "city": "Paris",
        "description": "Tour Eiffel"
    }
]
```

and this is the snippet from MyActivity:

```
try {
                        JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(loadJSON());
                        JSONObject jobject = jarray.getJSONObject(0);
                        String urlAddress = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q="+ jobject.getString("latitude")  +"," + jobject.getString("longitude") +"("+ jobject.getString("description") + " - " + jobject.getString("city") + ")&iwloc=A&hl=it";
                        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlAddress));
                        intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

very weird situation, loading your json:

```
private String loadJSON(){
    return "[{\"id\": \"1\","+ 
            "\"latitude\": \"48.8586006\","+
            "\"longitude\": \"2.2939799\","+
            "\"city\": \"Paris\","+
            "\"description\": \"Tour Eiffel\""+
            "}];";
}
```

with the method:

```
private void loadGoogleMap(){
    try {
        JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(loadJSON());
        JSONObject jobject = jarray.getJSONObject(0);
        String urlAddress = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q="+ jobject.getString("latitude")  +"," + jobject.getString("longitude") +"("+ jobject.getString("description") + " - " + jobject.getString("city") + ")&iwloc=A&hl=it";
        Log.e(TAG, "urlAddress : " + urlAddress);
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlAddress));
        intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
        startActivity(intent);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Load this url into Google Maps:

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=48.8586006,2.2939799(Tour Eiffel - Paris)&iwloc=A&hl=it

**I think it must be a problem related with cache, try clearing Google maps cache!**